# Properties are not showing in react native text component in map function

Tags: react-native, text, react-navigation, react-props

There are two screens addcity and cities. I am sending data from addcity via props and receiving in cities properly and I am trying to iterate data from props via map function but it is not printing data on my device, in fact, I have checked in the console and it is showing data correctly but not in View.

I am using react-naviagtion library with bottomtabnavigator and sending props with navigation props.

```
app.js 

state = {
    cities: []
  }

addCity = city => {
    const cities = this.state.cities;
    cities.push(city);
    this.setState({ cities })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs screenProps={{ cities: this.state.cities, addCity: this.addCity }} />
    )
  }
```

```
   cities component

   render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.props.screenProps.cities.map((city, index) => {
            console.log(city);
            <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{city.city}</Text>
          })
        }
       </View>
      )
    }
  }
```

```
 addcity component

 onSubmit = () => {
  if (this.state.city === '' || this.state.country === '') return
  const city = {
    id: uuidV4(),
    city: this.state.city,
    country: this.state.country,
    locations: []
  }
  this.props.screenProps.addCity(city);
  this.setState({
    city: '',
    country: ''
  }, () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Cities') });
}

render() {
  console.log('props', this.props);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>Cities App</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='City' value={this.state.city} onChangeText={val => this.onChangeTextInput('city', val)} />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='Country' value={this.state.country} onChangeText={val => this.onChangeTextInput('country', val)} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSubmit}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Add City </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
}
```

I am expecting to be city name in Text Component but it showing empty, even though I checked the console and it's consoling my data properly

Answer (score 1):

modify cities component like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.props.screenProps.cities.map((city, index) => {
            console.log(city);
            return (
              <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{city.city}</Text>
            )
          })
        }
       </View>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: bhai line break krke likha to nae chal ra tha code unreachable code ki warning ari thi...

Comment: phr ye krdia...return <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{city.city}</Text>

Answer (score 0):

Your map function should construct the text element and return it, you're not returning it.